# FontAwesome text inline on icon

Tags: css, angular, icons, font-awesome

[image]

So, I am using Angular and started using FontAwsome. I want to put the text inline, not in 3 lines like in the image above.

The above text is "4 BANJA LUKA".

The other solution would be to make the margins between the lines smaller, so it can fit the icon without making the icon too large (for example 4x or 5x).

Does anybody know the solution?

`<span class="fa-stack"> <i class="fas fa-comment-alt fa-3x" style="color:yellow;"></i> <i class="fa-stack-1x" style="font-size:10px;">4 BANJA LUKA</i> </span>`

Comment: Please provide your sample code here

Comment: thanks for the heads up, I forgot.

Answer (score 0):

1. One Way

you are want below manner to add font awesome.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome